# Change brightness on image with text on hover

Tags: css, hover

I have some images with text on them. I want to change the brightness of the images when hovered, without affecting the text.

The solution I have now works except for one issue: when the cursor moves over the image, the brightness changes, but if the cursor then moves over the text on top of the image, the brightness changes back.

How can I avoid this? I'm looking for a pure CSS solution, if possible.

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}
.image-container img {
  filter: brightness(60%);
  width: 100%;
}
.image-container img:hover {
  filter: brightness(100%);
}
.image-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #f6f6f6;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
<p><a href="/distancer/master/"><img src="https://yacs.dk/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Yeti_AR2_016-652-1.jpg"><br>
<span class="image-text">Master</span><br>
</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no brightness increase for text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger the change when hovering the container, instead of the image.

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}

.image-container img {
  filter: brightness(60%);
  width: 100%;
}

.image-container:hover img {
  filter: brightness(100%);
}

.image-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #f6f6f6;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <p>
    <a href="/distancer/master/"><img src="https://yacs.dk/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Yeti_AR2_016-652-1.jpg"><br>
      <span class="image-text">Master</span><br>
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `pointer-events:none` to ignore the hover event on the text

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}
.image-container img {
  filter: brightness(60%);
  width: 100%;
}
.image-container img:hover {
  filter: brightness(100%);
}
.image-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #f6f6f6;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  pointer-events:none
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
<p><a href="/distancer/master/"><img src="https://yacs.dk/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Yeti_AR2_016-652-1.jpg"><br>
<span class="image-text">Master</span><br>
</a></p>
</div>
```